Why doesn't my home button work when using the same js file on multiple html pages?
I am making a simple site, and I have three following files:
1st file:
# home.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
    <br />
    <button id="about">About me</button>
    <button id="contact">Contact me</button>
    <button id="pricing">Pricing</button>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

2nd file:
# about_me.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About me page</h1>
    <br />
    <button id="home">Home</button>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

3rd file:
# index.js
document.querySelector("#about").addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.href="about_me.html"
    })
    
    document.querySelector("#contact").addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.href="contact_me.html"
    })
    
    
    document.querySelector("#home").addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.href="home.html"
    })

The problem I am having is the following:
When I am at the home.html and click About me button, it takes me to the about_me.html file, but when I am in that page and click Home button it does nothing.
I have tried adding the JS code inside about_me.html file and it works that way.
Why it doesn't work this way?
P.S. All of the files are in the same folder. And it works if I separate them in different JS files.

This is not what <button> elements are for. Button elements are for performing on-page actions like submitting a form or opening a dialog. But you're trying to use buttons for another purpose: navigating users to a new location. This is not a job for buttons. There's another element specifically created for that purpose: Anchor elements, which don't require JavaScript at all.

Try using:
window.location = destinationPage;

Or:
window.location.assign(destinationPage);

Instead of:
window.location.href = destinationPage;

Also, it would be good assign your events like this:
document.addEventListener
(
   'readystatechange', Event =>
   {
      if ( document.readyState == 'interactive' ) // or 'complete'
      {
         // The DOM is ready for management.
         // Assign your events here.
      }
   }
);

FULL SOLUTION:


// #index.js

const sitePages =
{
  'home': 'home.html',
  'about': 'about_me.html',
  'contact': 'contact_me.html',
  'pricing': 'service_pricing.html',
}

document.addEventListener
(
  'readystatechange', readyEvent =>
  {
    if ( readyEvent.target.readyState == 'interactive' )
    {
      for ( const buttonIdentifier in sitePages )
      {
        document.querySelector(`#${buttonIdentifier}`)?.addEventListener
        (
          'click', buttonEvent =>
          {
            const siteURL = sitePages[buttonIdentifier];
            const newURL = new URL(siteURL, new URL('.', document.location.href)).href;
            
            console.log('Should go to: ' + newURL);
            
            // Uncomment the next line to actually redirect.
            // document.location = newURL;
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
);
<!-- file: home.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test website</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
    <br />
    <button id="about">About me</button>
    <button id="contact">Contact me</button>
    <button id="pricing">Pricing</button>
</body>
</html>

<!-- file: about_me.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About me</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About me page</h1>
    <br />
    <button id="home">Home</button>
</body>
</html>




Even when I put .assing or .location it doesn't work. But when I separate them into two JS files (one for home.html and one for the other two) it works.

@SolidOpt, I made a full solution. I hope it solves your problem.

This worked in the end:
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Check which element was clicked using event.target
    if (event.target.matches("#about")) {
        window.location.href = "about_me.html";
    } else if (event.target.matches("#contact")) {
        window.location.href = "contact_me.html";
    } else if (event.target.matches("#home")) {
        window.location.href = "home.html"
    }
});


For a portfolio this should not be much. But calling this callback in the document.addEventListener("click", callback) for every click could make the performance worse if there were a lot of click event listeners... Just attach your click event listener at elements that actually do something when clicked.

For a portfolio this should not be much. But calling this callback in the document.addEventListener("click", callback) for every click could make the performance worse if there were a lot of click event listeners... Just attach your click event listener at elements that actually do something when clicked.

There's no real problem in the HTML documents, but instead the script file.
The problem is that JavaScript files load from top to bottom of the file. On the about page, it can't find a button going to the about button, so it provides an error in the console and stops loading the rest.
You can fix this by moving the order, which I don't recommend that, because it will still result in an error although it will work.
What I would do is make separate JavaScript files, I would like "a" tags (hyperlinks), or I would check to see if there was a button before adding an event listener to it, like this:


if (document.querySelector("#about")) {
  document.querySelector("#about").addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.location.href = "about_me.html";
  });
}

if (document.querySelector("#about")) {
  document.querySelector("#contact").addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.location.href = "contact_me.html";
  });
}

if (document.querySelector("#home")) {
  document.querySelector("#home").addEventListener("click", function () {
    window.location.href = "home.html";
  });
}



I've been trying to post this for like 20 minutes, but I just posted on another question so I had to wait 30 minutes.
I just saw your response, and it works but the only problem is it runs for every button on the page, which is possible to make it lag if there's a lot of interactivity.

Could be solved by simply document.querySelector(button_id)?.addEventListener(...).

I think that’s in Typescript, not in plain JavaScript.

Well, I copied your code and found out that the index.js file works only from home.html file,
because I tried to define variables for those buttons and log them into the console while I was in about.html page but it logs nothing,
Therefore you're in front of two options:

either create another js file and link it to about.html ONLY! and put the home button click event in it, and this will work fine.

Or else put the text inside the button element into a tag and put the href value to the wanted page destination, For example:
Instead of:
<button id="home">Home</button> Use: <a href="home.html">Home</a>


Both of these methods will work but I recommend you the second one anyway.

It is invalid HTML to put an anchor inside a button.

@Sean, You're wrong. QUOTE: " elements are much easier to style than  elements. You can add inner HTML content (think , , or even ), and use ::after and ::before pseudo-elements for complex rendering." FROM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

@Sean, But it's not good practice to put an anchor inside a button to do something. Because you'll need to click the text inside the button for it to actually work (won't work if the click is on the border or the padding space between the text and the border).

Well guys I saw the accessibility and best practice report on my axe devtools, extension, you're right it's valid but not good practice, therefore you can just put the anchor tag alone without any nested buttons

@KLASANGUI no, Sean is not wrong. When you scroll down to the "Technical summary" section on that page you linked to, it says there, "Permitted content: Phrasing content but there must be no Interactive content" - and a falls into the "interactive content" category, and is therefor not allowed inside of button. (Or vice versa.)

@C3roe. Yes, strictly speaking, he is indeed wrong. Anchors can actually be put inside a button. <a> only is "Interactive Content" if it has the href attribute. Besides that, most browsers just allow using href as well (though tecnically it shouldn't). So, strictly, "<a>: It is invalid HTML to put an anchor inside a button." is an incorrect statement, because anchors can be put inside buttons (with a technical exception that is the href attribute). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content for more details.

@KLASANGUI " only is "Interactive Content" if it has the href attribute" - okay, but that was the original content within this answer, that Sean was referring to. If it is a non-interactive anchor, then it might be put into a button, alright. Although I've never had a use case in which that would have made much sense either.

@KLASANGUI I'm not wrong. <button><a href="home.html"></a></button> is invalid. Put it in a validator.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Sean I said you're wrong about (strictly) the sentence "It is invalid HTML to put an anchor inside a button." because an anchor can indeed be put inside a button (named anchors for instance). Please, read the 6th comment.
